# Check if pictures overlap and put them under each other

Tags: jquery, html, position, css-position

I'm creating a documentation page for some software that our company creates. Now, I want to be able to give a piece of text in a span tag with an attribute (data-fig-attach). jQuery then reads those tags and knows which picture should go where. I've written the following piece of code for it and it works like a charm:

Javascript (jQuery):

```
var fig_id = null;
$(function(){
    $("[data-fig-attach]").each(function(){
        var top_p = $(this).position().top;
        var fig_id = $(this).data().figAttach;
        $('[data-fig]').each(function(){
            var image = $(this);
            if($(this).data().fig == fig_id){
                image.css({
                    top: top_p,
                    position: 'absolute'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Text part -->
<span>Lorem ipsum <span style="font-weight:bold;" data-fig-attach="1">reiciendis</span> consequatur unde quidem illum odio natus! Labore, impedit, repellendus, dolorum animi deserunt quasi dolore magnam fugit quam ad nesciunt in.</span>

<!-- Picture part -->
<div data-fig="1"><img class="art-lightbox" src="http://www.scope4mation.com/docs/files/2013/11/ESB-Overview-1.png" alt="" width="300" height="203"><br/><em>Figure 4: This is something quite different</em></div>
```

The problem however, is that the pictures can overlap because I use `position: 'absolute'`. Is there a way to place the second picture a certain amount of pixels away from the first one? To clarify, I created a (rather large) picture to show exactly what I want :)

[image]

Can someone help me with this problem? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the proposed top for the new element is below the bottom of the previous picture. Here's a fiddle to demonstrate what I'm talking about: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xb25p/1)

Here's the jQuery I've modified:

```
var fig_id = null;
$(function(){
    $("[data-fig-attach]").each(function(){
        var top_p = $(this).position().top;
        var fig_id = $(this).data().figAttach;
        $('[data-fig]').each(function(i, e){
            var image = $(this);
            if($(this).data().fig == fig_id){
                // Make sure we're not at the first element
                if (i != 0) {
                    // Let's check the bottom of the previous element
                    var prev_e = $('[data-fig]').eq(i-1);
                    var prev_bot = prev_e.position().top + prev_e.height();
                    // Buffer size is how far apart you want your pictures to be, in pixels
                    var buff_size = 20;
                    // Now check to see if our proposed top is overlapping the previous
                    if (top_p < prev_bot + buff_size) {
                        // Change our new top to the bottom of the previous element, plus our buffer
                        top_p = prev_bot + buff_size;   
                    }
                }
                image.css({
                    top: top_p,
                    right: 0,
                    position: 'absolute'
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `outerHeight()` of the current `data-fig` to the `top_p value`. Or is that not what you want? And why do you use that second each, you can directly query for the data-fig element with the correct value. Hope this helps..

On an unrelated note; it's probably better to avoid absolute positioning in such a case, maybe you should step back and rethink if you're not overcomplicating things..

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/LP5Ta/

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $("[data-fig-attach]").each(function() {
            var top_p = $(this).position().top;
            var fig_id = $(this).data('fig-attach');
            var image = $('[data-fig=' + fig_id + ']');
            image.css({
                top: top_p,
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        });
        $('[data-fig]').slice(1).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $prev = $this.prev();
            var h1 = $prev.outerHeight();
            var h2 = $this.outerHeight();
            var t1 = parseInt($prev.css('top')) + h1;
            var t2 = parseInt($this.css('top')) + h2;
            if (t2 - t1 < h2) {
                $(this).css('top', t1);
            }
        });
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

This will also adjust the positions when the window is resized. You can adjust the minimum gap between images by adjusting the CSS.